# how to stop a script running in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i am running a script in **Zend Framework 2**, the issue is how to stop the script from proceeding if certain conditions are not met

below is my function, you will note that i attempted to redirect the script if the condition of  **willMemberAcceptMessage()** was not met

```
if(!$this->willMemberAcceptMessage())
        {  
            $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage(static::ERROR_UNABLE_TO_PROCEED);
            $this->redirect()->toUrl($url);
        }
```

the problem is that the script does not redirect straight away, it still keeps running.

what should i do?

Comment: add exit(); after redirect line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the correct approach is to *return* the result of the redirect helper call, as each of its methods return the response object:

```
if (!$this->willMemberAcceptMessage()) {  
    $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage(static::ERROR_UNABLE_TO_PROCEED);
    return $this->redirect()->toUrl($url);
}
```

You should avoid `exit;` calls if possible, and in this case, if you exit no redirect will happen.

Comment: Hello again Tim . Once again, i offer my deepest gratitude to you. you are correct. silly little mistake on my part. thanks

Answer (score 2):

add exit after redirect line

```
if(!$this->willMemberAcceptMessage())
        {  
            $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage(static::ERROR_UNABLE_TO_PROCEED);
            $this->redirect()->toUrl($url);
            exit;

        }
```